# Preventing exit from full screen mode in Adobe Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I'm using adobe Photoshop CS6

my question :

Sometimes my hand is just too fast that i accidentally press "escape" and i go back to the usual screen view, i want to stay in full screen mode without having too worry if i press escape too much. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Pry the ESC key off the keyboard ? :)

Comment: have you tried to create a custom workspace?

Answer (score 3):

You can change which shortcuts Photoshop uses by going Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts

There's definitely options for changing the screen mode but I'm not sure if you can turn off the escape/exit functionality, it may be hardcoded. If you want to easily see all the shortcuts you're using, click the 'Summarize' button to save out an HTML doc that lists them all.